# See processes/programs spawned off by another

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, process

I want to see all the processes/exes in memory that are spawned off when I click an application in windows 7, 64 bit. I could use Process monitor to do this, but I am not 
sure if it is the right tool. Also, I don't know how to filter the relevant parent 
process instead of seeing all processes running on the computer.

An example of what I expect - When I run Chrome browser, I should see all the files (its own or windows exes) and processes which it calls and loads into memory/ram.

The reason for doing all this - My commercial firewall is blocking an application. I added the exe of the app to firewall exceptions and also the port of the server which this app is trying to access. Both methods failed. But, this piece of information is proabably not relevant to this question.

Comment: One more question - I have been suggested process hacker and process explorer. Which one is "better" ?

Comment: Process Monitor is the correct tool and none of the 2 others.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use [SystemInternal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx)'s Process Explorer (procexp). You could get just procexp, but all the utilities are useful so grab the whole suite.
[image: Here's a subsection, showing a process tree spawned from chrome. Further exploration is possible.]

Comment: How can the user use this to see what they want?

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the [`Process Hacker`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) for this.

[image]

Many of you have probably used Process Explorer in the past. Process Hacker has several advantages:

- Process Hacker allows you to copy data by simply pressing Ctrl+C.
- Process Hacker is open source and can be modified or redistributed.
- Process Hacker does not have several year old bugs that still remain unfixed.
- Process Hacker is more customizable.
- Process Hacker shows symbolic access masks (e.g. *Read*, *Write*), rather than just numbers (e.g. *0x12019f*).

Comment: How can the user use this to see what they want?